# PhpStorm (2021+) - SFTP by the way of a SSH tunnel

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, ssh-tunnel

For deployment, I must connect to SFTP `RemoteSftp.com:123` using private key.

But, I must first use a SSH tunnel to access the `RemoteSftp.com` on `GateSftp.com:456` with an other username and other private key.

Any idea how to configure this sort of tunnel n PhpStorm?

Comment: Not a SSH expert by any means, just a possible hint: will `ProxyCommand` and/or `ProxyJump` be able to do this? Should be. `ProxyCommand` is supported, `ProxyJump` is not but can be work-arounded by ProxyCommand anyway. Check this comment and mentioned tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26199/Support-tunneling-via-SSH-deployment-upload#focus=Comments-27-5203671.0-0

Comment: You mean the Proxy settings in the SSH config ? The problem is that it do not accept KeyPair Authentication, only user/pass ... so i can't even try .

Comment: No. The link from that comment: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand -- from `~/.ssh/config` (`%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\config` on Windows) file. If KeyPair Authentication can be done in command line then it _should_ work in `ProxyCommand` as well IMO. Check comments in both linked tickets (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72040 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214679) for example commands and see how you can use it for your setup.

Comment: Proxy for SSH (and SFTP in that case) is already available in latest PhpStorm versions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72040/Support-proxy-for-SSH-implying-SFTP-for-Deployment#focus=Comments-27-5251236.0-0 @Ledahu please try to configure your connection with the help of that link

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you can connect to the server using `ssh remotesftp`, then it should work in jetbrains.

Make a configuration file for ssh. On linux/macOS that is `~/.ssh/config`, `%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\config` for Windows.

```
# The gate ssh server
Host gatesftp
    User         root
    Port         456
    HostName     GateSftp.com
    IdentityFile /path/to/gatesftp/private/key

# The deployment server
Host remotesftp
    User         root
    Port         123
    HostName     RemoteSftp.com
    IdentityFile /path/to/remotesftp/private/key
    ProxyJump    gatesftp
```

*Note: when you do a proxy jump, the keys from your local machine applies to both. You don't need to let the gate server hold the key*

When this is set up, and can confirm you have a connection to the server by doing `ssh remotesftp`, then you can follow these steps in jetbrains:

1. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `SSH Configurations`
2. Add a new (or edit) connection.
3. For Authentication type, choose `OpenSSH config and authentication agent`
4. Host: `remotesftp`, Port: `22`, Username: `root` (strangely this works)